# I cringe when asking questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, community

Whenever I ask a question on Stack Overflow, or any Stack Exchange site, such as

> How can I change x to do y

it seems that the community is most interested in pointing out my question is stupid, either by not answering my question at all

> You shouldn't even have x in the first place
>
> Your capitalization is very wrong

or by thinking that if the answer is obvious to them, it should be obvious to me.

> *me, in a comment on an answer*: "I'm sorry, I don't overly understand what you mean. Can you provide an example?"
>
> *counter comment*: "@Matthew: What do you think happens to your SqlParameter?"

Is there a way I can avoid this? How can I know if my question will be considered annoying?

Should I prepost every question on meta and ask if it's appropriate?

I want to get the most out of Stack Exchange sites, and feel that I need to improve the way I ask my questions. Basically, how do I phrase them to make the community more receptive to them? Any tips?

Comment: Maybe you are wording your questions incorrectly. Try having a read through this  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: For context: The [question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369686/error-must-declare-the-scalar-variable).... Hmm, I'm not an expert in the subject matter and SLaks is admittedly being a bit harsh, but I think you may be taking the tone too seriously. After all, it's constructive input. Also note that the remark about capitalization - as far as I can tell, a hint on improving coding style - was made by the same user who gave you the actual answer to the question.

Comment: We've all been there, don't take it personally.

Comment: SLaks is SLaks, but a Diamond-Moderator should really not express himself that way. This goes totally against the "be nice" entry in the SO FAQ (edit: I realize now that this was posted when he wasn't a moderator yet, but still ...)

Comment: +1, I'm with you. Sometimes you just want to know how something works to know how it works, not because you want to make a dangerous kludge or stupid micro-optimization or whatever else the answerers are assuming.

Comment: @MatthewU - if you find a comment offensive you can flag it.

Comment: @BalusC - I didn't interpret it as rude, merely laconic.

Comment: @BalusC yeah, true, the tone in that one is not nice. But looking at the OP's question history, this seems like a relatively isolated incident to me. Not enough to make a generalization... Although I can symphatize with the point @Popular makes

Comment: People being a little hard on new users or new developers has been a concern for a while (see [Could we please be a bit nicer to the noobs?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs)), but I don't think that's the case here.  I don't think SLaks is being harsh, he's just trying to help.

Comment: I've had my fair share of negative commentary with SLaks too ;) [but he seems to have toned down a tad lately, so lets hope it stays that way :D ]

Comment: @BalusC: You are aware that SLaks wasn't a diamond moderator when he posted that answer?

Comment: @R.Bemrose: Yes. Are you also aware of the edit in my comment which I made within the minute?

Comment: @BalusC: No, because you hadn't yet edited it when I loaded this page before replying.

Comment: @R.Bemrose: That's indeed possible.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, been there. Sometimes the responses can be harsh. This question (disclaimer: that I asked) and the many useful answers will I think help a lot:

- **[What advice would you give beginners joining a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/what-advice-would-you-give-beginners-joining-a-stack-exchange-site)**

e.g.

- Don't take personal criticism to heart.
- Do the homework before posting a question.
- Post the context of your question.

to name just a few.

Answer (score 4):

Now that I've had a moment to read the linked question above

He was offering two specific pieces of advice/commentary:

There's an *accepted* naming scheme on MS projects, that we all pretty well use to keep things readable cross-domain (so if we share code, we both read it the same) and he as advising you (in a succinct manner) to change how you were casing your program code.

He was asking *what do you think* happens to the SqlParameter and you ignored his question. (or deleted something, idk)

So: Context helps. Responses help. Asking "what do you mean by that comment, I'm confused" helps.

HTH