# How do I get 5 reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

How do I get started?

If you need 5 points to answer a question why do you need to ask needless questions to get 5 points?

Comment: Are you talking about answering a question on a child meta, like [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: And related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/what-advice-would-you-give-beginners-joining-a-stack-exchange-site/64943#64943

Comment: I went to answer a question and got a message that I needed 5 points to answer I have one, therefore my account is useless so how do i earn points without answering a question?

Comment: The links I provided answer that and check what @ArthurFischer commented...

Comment: @ApexCapstone: The only places that require *five* points of rep to answer/ask are child metas, which don't earn you any rep anyway. Otherwise, enderland's answer and rene's dupe-link seem the best match.

Comment: You'll do well around the Stack Exchange sites if you spend a little time investigating the Help Centers on each site you visit, using the search function, and viewing the Meta for that site. For example, searching here instead of asking your question would have returned a lot of results for numerous different keywords.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need 5 points to answer a question.

Some questions will be "protected" so new users cannot answer them, however, this is to prevent spam (or lots of low quality posts) generally.